# Select an array in mysql with match id array and calculate

Tags: php, mysql, select

i have my post value example from a form textbox:

```
<input type="number" name="m_id[<?php echo $row['m_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['m_id']; ?>"/>

<input type="number" name="qty[<?php echo $row['m_id']; ?>]" value=""/>
```

in my php code:

```
$id = $_POST['m_id'];
$qty = $_POST['qty'];
```

lets assume that the post array has values id 2,4,5 with qty input 1,1,1

```
id    qty
2     1
4     1
5     1
```

How can i select a table named sup_mon like:

```
sup_mon table:
      m_id    balance
       1         2
       2         5
       3         20
       4         15 
       5         8

the select will be:
      m_id    balance
       2         5
       4         15 
       5         8
```

how can I subtract the balance from the qty array input 1,1,1 in the corresponding m_id.

Comment: My initial guess would be a query.

Comment: exactly how does this qty of 1 affect your data? your balances aren't changing between the two tables. all you'er doing is eliminating some rows that weren't present in the id's.

Comment: do you need to get the result of the subtraction ? otherwise you could just do an `UPDATE` query

Comment: Do you want to just display the difference on the screen, or do you want to subtract the value from the balance in the database?

Comment: yes i need it for updating another table.. please help.

Comment: i dont understand anything. what have you tried or what array you want to use where ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop with an update query for each id. You didn't mention a database connection style, so I'll use PDO. NOTE: This code assumes that there is a qty for every id. You'll also need to change the update statement to match your database name, etc...

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['id']); $i++) {

    $sql = "UPDATE databaseName.sup_mon SET balance = balance - :qty WHERE m_id = :id";

    //if you're debugging, you may want to uncomment the next line:
    //echo $sql;

    //here $dbh is a PDO object - database handler
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);

    //binds the current id value from the post array
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $_POST['id'][$i], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':qty', $_POST['qty'][$i], PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: why do you bind only one param ?

Comment: Good call! That would open it up to sql injection, wouldn't it now? Will edit answer...